# how do I refer to a QuerySet element in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have such a QuerySet:

```
'category_1': Product.objects.filter(category__slug='white')
```

how
how can I refer to a certain element of this QuerySet? for example, like referring to the elements of a list.

in template:

```
{{ category_1[1].image.url }}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{ category_1.1.image.url }}`
Django templates use dot notation, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/#variables).